# FragmentManager replace fragments without calling onPause() onDestroy() for the old fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, pull-to-refresh, fragmentmanager

In my application, I have a left menu that controls `Fragment` transactions in one `FragmentView` in my `MainActivity`. Above the `FragmentView` I have the new `PullToRefresh` component that is used in the new GMAIL only being refreshed in only one `Fragment`.

[image]

I want to stop the refreshing of it if I have replaced this `Fragment` with another one.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new pullToRefreshFragment())
            .commit();
```

I expected that the `FragmentManager` stick to the traditional [FragmentLifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) then, I decided to stop the `PullToRefresh` component in `onPause`, `onDestroy`, `onStop` or `onDetach()` methods. Unfortunately, Those method never been called on replacing the `Fragment`. They only been replace if I have selected the same fragment from the left menu.

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    if(mPullToRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()){
        mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshComplete();
    }
    super.onDetach();
}
```

That means that, the `FragmentManager` is caching the fragments and does not destroy them unless if I am trying to replace a fragment with another fragment from the same Type.

**My question is, What is the fragment lifeCycle in case of replacing or adding a new fragment over another one using `FragmentManager`?**

**Where should I stop my PullToRerfesh component, if I want to stop it when replacing the fragment with another one?**

Comment: I'm just asking the same thing... very interesting question but I'm affraid that nobody has the answer...